# Как переименовать файл в Android

Tags: android, файловая-система

При записи на память телефона все переименовывает, но при работе  sd card с файлами папки DCIM ничего не происходит. Как решить эту проблему?

Gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.hide.hidefiles"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Код:

```
String strFileName = "/storage/363B-2D26/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140610_174832.jpg" //файл существует 100%    
File oldFile = new File(strFileName);
File renameFile = new File(strFileName.replaceAll(".jpg",".jp"));
boolean res = oldFile.renameTo(renameFile);
```

В итоге `res` равно `false` - переименования не происходит.

Проблема вот в чем:

```
oldFile.canRead()=true
oldFile.canWrite()=false
```

Разрешения у приложения есть, работаю в android 6, проверил разрешения через настройки приложения - там все ок. Права - Память устройства есть

Видимо, нет доступа на запись - как его получить?
При этом из приложения открыл фото, и переименовал его руками через стандартное меню, все нормально. ничего не понимаю

[image: Экран отладчика]

права получены все ок

в activity

```
PermissionDialog.requestRead_Internet_StatePermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, this);
        PermissionDialog.requestRead_Internet_StatePermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, this);
```

Есть класс

```
public class PermissionDialog {

    //Открывает запрос на Permission
    public static void  requestRead_Internet_StatePermission(String permission, Activity context) {

        int rc = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission);
        if (rc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        final String[] permissions = new String[]{permission};

        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(context,
                permission)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, permissions, 1);
            return;
        }

        final Activity thisActivity = context;

        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity, permissions,
                        1);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Проблему не решил! [права есть](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIXRk.png)
[image: права на запись есть]

Comment: Вы не написали главного. Что не так с вашим кодом?

Comment: и что ни так c моим кодом?

Comment: зачем вы вопросом на вопрос отвечаете? У вас, видимо, какая-то проблема, раз вы задали тут вопрос. Видимо приведённый вами код не делает то что нужно. Но вы не написали что именно происходит - ничего или ошибка какая-то возникает. Как мы вам поможем если вы главного не говорите - в чём именно вам нужна помощь.\

Comment: я понял, извините, правлю

Comment: 1. Какой API level вы используете? 2. `<uses-permission ... >` находится до `<application>`?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ivanovolegdevstudio.hide.hidefiles"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: @ivansoft, если вы тестируете на 6+ версии оси, то разрешение на запись надо запрашивать в рантайме. Или вручную включить в настройках приложения

Comment: @ivansoft, а это у вас так на всех девайсах не работает? Может быть стоит попробовать тогда создавать новый файл, а старый удалять?

Answer (score 1):

Так как у вас в качестве `targetSdkVersion` указан API level 23+, то нужно не только указывать права в манифесте, но и запрашивать права в самом коде:

```
// Storage Permissions
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

/**
 * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
 *
 * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to grant permissions
 *
 * @param activity
 */
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
```

Код взят из [соответствующего ответа на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33292700/3432401), который основывается на [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: с правами все ок

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь, но пока проблему не решил. Мистика...